# Nvidia 630m not working to run games

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-geforce

I have a Lenovo Z480 laptop with graphics card 630m, Core i5 3210m 2.50 Ghz & 6Gb RAM but I am unable to run games on my Nvidia Graphics Card.

I have tried many times to run games on Nvidia card through Nvidia Control Panel but I am unable to run games on the card, please if someone is familiar with this problem advise me how to use the card to play games.

Comment: could you specify "unable to run games"? Is there any error message or something?

Comment: Agreed with user1220636, without explaining what the error is, it's very hard to help.

Comment: which games? what do you mean by run games through nvidia control panel?

Comment: get nvidia drivers from nvidia.com/drivers and install them...quite easy

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about right install your graphic driver? check your correct Nvidia driver and install on your device. Please check and install Intel Turbo Boost from your CD installation driver.

Comment: i have tried to install the drivers two times but it says that 'the graphic card driver could not find compatible graphics hardware' few days ago it was working i had run two games on my nvidia card but now it is not working to run the games.

Comment: i also dont have much knowledge to run games on laptop because i have usually used desktop for gaming & in desktop i have never met with such problem.

Comment: PROBLEM IS THAT LAPTOP IS USING INTEGRATED MEMORY TO PLAY GAMES BUT NOT THE GRAPHICS CARD MEMORY DUE TO WHICH GAMES ARE RUNNING SLOWLY AND I HAVE MADE DEFAULT AS NVIDIA GRAPHICS PROCESSOR TO RUN GAMES BUT LAPTOP IS USING INTEGRATED MEMORY

Comment: I have got an other problem in my laptop ,all the 'exe' files of games are removed automically, i dont know its cause, i have also reinstalled the game 'Special Ops:The Line', before this problem the game was running but now it is giving the error that 'the XINPUT1_3.dll is missing from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your VGA driver is not correct for your laptop.find the correct driver from Lenovo site and install it. check the this site for find easy Nvidia driver http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073552 . I sure your Nvidia driver is not detected on your windows.

Comment: I have got an other problem in my laptop ,all the 'exe' files of games are removed automically, i dont know its cause, i have also reinstalled the game 'Special Ops:The Line', before this problem the game was running but now it is giving the error that 'the XINPUT1_3.dll is missing from your computer

Comment: I have also downloaded & installed the drivers that 'Mohammad Hasan' suggested me.

Comment: your laptop has some viruses. check your Antivirus and update it.

Comment: i think you are right my laptop is again not running the games on nvidia card.Few hours earlier i played two games 'Spec Ops:The line' & Fifa12' on max settings but now they are not running well on normal settings.